# how to simulate real cases where the shape of data are different from the shape of the training data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

as I know, when testing ML models, the shape of testing data should be the same shape of the data used to train the model. However, in real cases, the shape may be different (i.e number of features) for example network traffic.
How to use a pre trained model in real case where the shape of data is different of the shape of training data.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a one-size-fits-all answer to this question, as the best way to use a pre-trained model with different data shapes will vary depending on the model and the data. However, some general tips that may be helpful include:

-Ensuring that the data used to train the model is representative of the data that will be used in the real-world application. This will help to avoid issues such as overfitting.

-Using data augmentation techniques to generate additional data that is similar to the real-world data. This can help to increase the size of the training dataset, as well as making it more representative of the real-world data.

-Tuning the model hyperparameters to optimize performance on the real-world data. This may require some trial and error, but can help to ensure that the model performs well on the data that it will be used with in the real world.

Comment: in my case -for example-  I train a neural network (an example) with a benchmark dataset that represents network traffic. then I want to use the model in real network traffic. Surely, the features will not be the same. therefore, the number of nodes in the input layer will not be the same so an error will be occured here. How to fix this... Thank you for your reply